# Question about $p(z,w)=\alpha_0(z)+\alpha_1(z)w+\cdots+\alpha_k(z)w^k$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $p(z,w)=\alpha_0(z)+ \alpha_1(z)w+\cdots+\alpha_k(z)w^k$ ,where $k \le 1$ and $p(z,w)=\alpha_0(z)+ \alpha_1(z)w+\cdots+\alpha_k(z)w^k_0,\cdots, p(z,w)=\alpha_0(z)+ \alpha_1(z)w+\cdots+\alpha_k(z)w^k_k$ are non-constant polynomials in the complex variable $z$. Then:

$(z,w) \in C\times C:p(z,w)=0$ is:

- Bounded with empty interior.
- Unbounded with empty interior.
- bounded with nonempty interior .
- unbounded with nonempty interior.

How can I be able to solve this problem ? I have no idea at all.

Comment: Your first two lines with three versions of $p(z,w)$ and undefined $w_0$ and $w_k$ don't make sense. Also, $k\leq 1$ is very strange.

Answer (score 2):

If a complex polynomial is locally (on an open set) equal to zero, it is globally equal to zero.  Therefore the interior of the set of zeroes is empty since $p \neq 0$.  Each of the terms $\alpha_m$ has only finitely many zeroes.  In particular there are only finitely many $z \in \mathbb{C}$ for which $\alpha_m(z) = 0$ for all $m \in \{2, \dotsc, k\}$ simultaneously.  If $|z|$ is large enough then $z$ will not be an element of this finite set and $w \mapsto p(z,w)$ is a non-constant polynomial in $w$ which therefore has a zero in $\mathbb{C}$.  This shows that the set of zeroes of $p$ is unbounded.